# Oracle clean audit trails

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am trying to clean the unified audit trails using the plsql below

```
DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.clean_audit_trail(
audit_trail_type => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
use_last_arch_timestamp => TRUE);     
END;
/
```

ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # 19, block # 299907)
ORA-01110: data file 19: /home/oracle/oradata_tbs/kamobile/sysaux01.dbf

The file id 19 is under table CLI_SWP$80370d01$2$1 under AUDSYS schema, i tried to repair using the dbms_repair package and file is marked as mark_corrupt=TRUE, Finally i made the skip corrupt block.

I am trying to clean up the audit trail, but i always get the above error

And also the audit trails is not storing under the sys.unified_audit_trail table from then onwards.

Comment: which oracle version are you using ?

Comment: Standard edition one 12.0

Comment: what is the output of this query `select * from v$database_block_corruption;`

Comment: file  block   blocks  corruption_change  corruption_type conn_id
3 4713 1 0 FRACTURED 0 
19 299907 1 0 FRACTURED 0

Comment: the problem is that you can't use `RMAN> blockrecover corruption list;` , because it is only available for EE not for SE. I think you have to recreate the sysaux tablespace anyway.

Comment: Is there any issue if i keep the corrput block skip and we dont need audit trails

Comment: kindly guide me how to recreate a sysaux tablespace pls, i googled it but not a good post is seen

Comment: I would need to put this as an answer. Do you want this as an answer ?

Comment: A fractured block means that the header contains information different than the SCN contained in the data. http://oracle-help.com/oracle-database/fractured-block-oracle/

Comment: Every day at midnight the database is crashed,  how to identify the reason behind that

Comment: check the alert log of the database, and you will find the reason why the db is crashing